# Ограничить замены .replace

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как ограничить количество замен, производимых методом `.replace`? Допустим

```
text = text.replace(/test/g, 'new')
```

Заменит все слова `test` на слова `new`. Как сделать, чтобы заменены были только первые три встреченных слова (соответствия регулярному выражению)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Еще вариант с функцией подстановки

```js
function createReplacer(max, newString) {
  var cur = 0
  return function($1) {
    if (cur < max) {
      cur += 1;
      return newString;
    }
    return $1;
  }
}
var text = "test 1 test 2 test 3 test 4 test 5"
document.body.innerHTML = text + '<br/>';
document.body.innerHTML += text.replace(/test/g, createReplacer(4, "new"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Может я чего-то не понимаю, но модификатор `g` вроде как включает global match. Без него `replace` сработает только 1 раз.

Так что, если вам надо 3 раза, то можно написать так:

```
text = text.replace(/test/, 'new').replace(/test/, 'new').replace(/test/, 'new');
```